# MasterPage - Downside to referencing Controls as properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, reference, master-pages

In my ASP.Net MasterPage I sometimes have controls that need to be accessed by most Pages.
Now instead of using this to access the control

```
((Label)this.Page.Master.FindControl("lblBreadCrumb")).Text = "foo";
```

I tend to put a Property in the MasterPage with a reference to the Control, set the @MasterType directive in the Page and access the control like this:

```
this.Master.BreadCrumb.Text = "foo";
```

I find this approach much easier to use, but I never actually saw someone do it like this so I wonder if there is any good reason against it that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using properties is a much better idea than using `FindControl` for several reasons, I'm glad that you're using this approach!
The most compelling reason to use properties is lets say you change the name of a control, or remove it all together. Now, you have a compiler error, which is much easier to spot. For example, if you rename `lblBreadCrumb` and you're using `FindControl`, the compiler will not catch this error, and instead your app will fail at run time. Catching errors at compile time is a great feature of a language.

The reason why you don't see many other developers doing this is because good OO design is hardly ever found in Web Forms unfortunately.

Comment: Great point with the compile time error! Thanks for pointing it out, never crossed my mind.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's a great approach when many pages will be accessing it.

Sometimes, I may abstract it a little more. For example, instead of simply accessing the control directly, I may just make a property on the master page like BreadCrumbText.